# loop only going through one set of data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble with looping through data when selecting an `All` option in one or both of relevant drop down menus. It is not going through all the records and displaying them, it is only going trough one set of data. It is suppose to display details for each student and for each question they have participated in. But it is only showing one student and one question and that is all.

Below is what it should display:

[image]

But instead at the moment it is just displaying this:

[image]

I believe what is causing this problem is the dynamic WHERE clause I have set up. Below is how dynamic WHERE clause works:

- Compulsory WHERE condition of `q.SessionId = ?`
- If user selects single student from student drop down menu, then add `AND sa.StudentId = ?` to WHERE clause
- If user selects  `All` students option from student drop down menu, then remove or do not display `AND sa.StudentId = ?` from WHERE clause
- If user selects single question from question drop down menu, then add `AND q.QuestionId = ?` to WHERE clause
- If user selects  `All` questions option from question drop down menu, then remove or do not display `AND q.QuestionId = ?` from WHERE clause

I have three drop down menus (below is what they look like with sample data):

**Session:**

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="26">POKUB1</option>
<option value="27">POKUB2</option>
</select>
```

**Student:**

```
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="39">Luke Mcfadzen</option>
<option value="40">Chris Tucker</option>
</select>
```

**Question:**

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="72">1</option>
<option value="73">2</option>
</select>
```

Don't forget how the WHERE condition is suppose to work which I mentioned above in this question. Lets say the session chosen from session drop down menu is `POKUB 1, drop down value: 26`.

If you select a single student and a single question, then it displays the details correctly e.g.

- **Student:** Luke McFadzen - drop down value: 39
- **Question:** 1 - drop down value: 72

So WHERE condition is `q.SessionId = 26 AND sa.StudentId = 39 AND q.QuestionId = 72`.

But if I select an `All` option in either or both student and question drop down menu, then the output only displays one student and one question and for some strange reason it combines answers from all questions and combines all student answer answers into the single output.

Now `All` option in both drop down menus has a drop down value of `0`, now `0` is not a value to select from database but we have stated in dynamic where clause that if a `0` value is chosen from a specific drop down menu, then remove the relevant condition from the WHERE clause, so for example:

- `All` students and single question (value `72`) - `WHERE q.SessionId
  = 26 AND q.QuestionId = 72`
- Single (value `39`) student and `All` questions - `WHERE q.SessionId
  = 26 AND sa.StudentId = 39`
- `All` students and `All` questions - `WHERE q.SessionId = 26`

**THE ABOVE SCENARIOS ARE HAVING THE PROBLEMS**

If I just left the query with a static WHERE clause `WHERE q.SessionId = ?` then it outputs the details correctly if I select `All` students and `All` Questions, but I need the query to work for all different possible options selected from the drop down menus and hence why I need a dynamic WHERE clause. How can I get it to work so the correct details are outputted?

Code:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
        SELECT
        sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
        q.QuestionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, 
        (
        SELECT sum( StudentMark )
        FROM Student_Answer sta
        WHERE sa.StudentId = sta.StudentId
        AND sa.QuestionId = sta.QuestionId
        )StudentMark
        FROM Student st
        INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
        INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId) AND sa.QuestionId = sr.QuestionId
        INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
        INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
        LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
        LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
        ";

        // Initially empty
        $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
        $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
        $parameterTypes = 'i';


        //check if POST is empty

        // Check whether a specific student was selected
        $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];

        switch($p_student){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }

        // Check whether a specific question was selected
        $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?'':$_POST["question"];

        switch($p_question){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }

        // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
        // our query
        if(!empty($where)) {
            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
            global $mysqli;
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
            // You only need to call bind_param once

            if (count($where) == 1) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 2) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 3) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
        }

        }

        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
          GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
          ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
        ";

    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,
    $detailsQuestionId,$detailsQuestionNo,$detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,
    $detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark); 

    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
    $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 

 while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

                //Check if the student data exist.
                if (!isset($questions[$detailsStudentId])) {
                    $questions[$detailsStudentId] = array(
                        'studentalias' => $detailsStudentAlias,
                        'studentforename' => $detailsStudentForename,
                        'studentsurname' => $detailsStudentSurname,
                        'questions' => array()
                    );
                }

                $questions[$detailsStudentId]['questions'][$detailsQuestionId] = array(
                    'questionno'=>$detailsQuestionNo,
                    'content'=>$detailsQuestionContent,
                    'optiontype'=>$detailsOptionType,
                    'noofanswers'=>$detailsNoofAnswers,
                    'answer'=>$detailsAnswer,
                    'replytype'=>$detailsReplyType,
                    'questionmarks'=>$detailsQuestionMarks,
                    'studentanswer'=>$detailsStudentAnswer,
                    'responsetime'=>$detailsResponseTime,
                    'mouseclick'=>$detailsMouseClick,
                    'studentmark'=>$detailsStudentMark
                );
            }

            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->close();

    foreach ($questions as $studentId => $studentData) {
        echo '<p>'.$studentData['studentalias'].' - '.$studentData['studentforename'].' '.$studentData['studentsurname'].'</p>';

        foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {
            echo '<p><strong>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'<br/>';
            echo $questionData['optiontype'].' - '.$questionData['noofanswers'].' - '.$questionData['answer'].' - '.$questionData['replytype'].' - '.$questionData['questionmarks'].'<br/>';
            echo $questionData['studentanswer'].' - '.$questionData['responsetime'].' - '.$questionData['mouseclick'].' - '.$questionData['studentmark'].'</strong></p>';
        }
    }
```

Below are the possible var_dumps for `$_POST['student']` and `$_POST['question']`:

**SINGLE STUDENT AND SINGLE QUESTION:**

- Student: Chris Tucker - string(2) "40"
- Question: 1 - string(2) "72"

**SINGLE STUDENT AND ALL QUESTIONS:**

- Student: Chris Tucker - string(2) "40"
- Question: All - string(1) "0"

**ALL STUDENTS AND SINGLE QUESTION:**

- Student: All - string(1) "0"
- Question: 1 - string(1) "72"

**ALL STUDENTS AND ALL QUESTIONS:**

- Student: All - string(1) "0"
- Question: All - string(1) "0"

Below is example `var_dump($questions);` if I select `All` students and `All` questions:

```
array(1) { 
[39]=> array(4) { 
["studentalias"]=> string(8) "u4838229" 
["studentforename"]=> string(5) "Chris" 
["studentsurname"]=> string(6) "Tucker" 
["questions"]=> array(1) { 
[72]=> array(11) { 
["questionno"]=> int(1) 
["content"]=> string(14) "What is a RAM?" 
["optiontype"]=> string(3) "A-E" 
["noofanswers"]=> int(1) 
["answer"]=> string(7) "B,C,D,E" 
["replytype"]=> string(6) "Single" 
["questionmarks"]=> int(5) 
["studentanswer"]=> string(9) "A,B,C,D,E" 
["responsetime"]=> string(8) "00:00:07" 
["mouseclick"]=> int(1) 
["studentmark"]=> string(1) "2" } } } }
```

**UPDATE:**

If I keep the mysqli query using a static WHERE clause when it just checks for `q.SessionId = ?` only, then when I select the `All` options in etiher or both drop down menus, it outputs the results fine no problem, only wither the dynamic where clause which I need to include as user my be able to select an indivdual student and/or indivdiual question that the `All` options do not work properly. Below is working mysqli code when using static WHERE clause:

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
    q.QuestionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, 
    (
    SELECT sum( StudentMark )
    FROM Student_Answer sta
    WHERE sa.StudentId = sta.StudentId
    AND sa.QuestionId = sta.QuestionId
    )StudentMark
    FROM Student st
    INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId) AND sa.QuestionId = sr.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
    INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
    LEFT JOIN Session_Taken sta ON (st.StudentId = sta.StudentId)
      WHERE q.SessionId = ?
      GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
      ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";
    global $mysqli;
$selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['session']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,
$detailsQuestionId,$detailsQuestionNo,$detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,
$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark);
```

Comment: working properly as coded... your dump only has one student/question in it... check how $questions is being built and see why there's only one student getting entered.

Comment: Another bounty on cheated rep points.

Comment: I really need help, does somebody have any ideas? the answer below is not a solution and really need a solution badly

Comment: [Some advises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14598007/285587) I gave to your fellow classmate. That's the only way to get help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense +1 for pointing to the old question and cheap trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty() considers a '0' as empty http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, 
so in `$p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];` $p_student is true when $_POST["student"] is '0'... As a result, the case below is always 'default', so you should may be set $p_student as a '0' if empty() and it should be ok...I think... ( Thats for both $p_student and $p_question of course...).
`

```
    $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?0:$_POST["student"];  // Now if $_POST['student'] is either 0 or empty $p_student will be 0

    switch($p_student){
    case 0:
        //dont' add where filters
        break;
    default:
        $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // Check whether a specific question was selected
    $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?0:$_POST["question"]; // Same here, if $_POST['question'] is either 0 or empty $p_question will be 0
    switch($p_question){
    case 0:
        //dont' add where filters
        break;
    default:
        $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }`
```

Comment: Can you show me code snippet for what this is, bounty is running out so need a quick solution so I can award bounty before it runs out

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code snippet but no luck, it is still doing same thing, any other ideas?

Comment: You should check if `$p_student` and `$p_question` has the right values before the 'cases' and also check `$selectedstudentanswerqry` right before you execute the query so you would know if there is something wrong with the query with the query itself or with the appended 'wheres'

Comment: I know the query is doing the right things correctly as I have previously done a var_dump on `$selectedstudentanswerqry` and the WHERE clause is working correctly depending on the options selected. I will have a check for $p_student and $p_question. Can I quickly ask should `$parameters[]` be followed by `.=` or `=`? and same from `$parameterTypes`?

Comment: When I echo `$p_student` and `$p_question` before their relevant switch statements, it does output the correct values.

Comment: I included update at bottom of question showing the code when it has a statci WHERE clause. Obviously I need a dynamic WHERE clause but what it informs is that with the static WHERE clause, it outputs the details with no problems if the user selects the `All` option in either or both dropdown menus. It just does not output all details properly when in dynamic WHERE clause.

Comment: The `$selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
          GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
          ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
        "` is executed after the `$selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);` so probably the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are not included in the query... I suppose...

Comment: That seems to make sense, but where shall I put it as if I just put the GROUP BY, ORDER BY statement above the prepare statement then it gives an error

Comment: Then put the prepare statement after the GROUP BY, ORDER BY statement :)

Comment: I can't have the bind_param(0 before the prepare statement if I move the prepare statement after GROUP BY, ORDER BY

Comment: Sorted it buddy, had to move the closing `}` like what user1914292 mentioned and then move the preapre statement underneath as you mentioend and move all the if statements which included the bind_param underneath the prepare statement and it all works fine. Can't believe this almost took 2 weeks to figure out lol. But thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the source of your problem is this:

```
    // Check whether a specific student was selected
    $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];

    switch($p_student){
    case 0:
        //dont' add where filters
        break;
    default:
        $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }
```

The code to add a student to the where clause is only being executed once, and does not support multiple students being selected.

Something like this should work, assuming you modify your code to pass an array of student ids from the form:

```
if (!empty($_POST['student'])) {

    $students = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'student', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if ($students !== false) {
        $num_students = count($students);
        $where[]      = 'sa.StudentId IN (' . rtrim(str_repeat('?,', $num_students), ',') . ')';
        $parameters   = array_merge($parameters, $students);
    }
}
```

A couple things:

- Never trust un-sanitized data, always sanitize/filter before using.
- If you add `[]` to the name of your form field (ie: `<select name="student[]">` PHP will interpret it as an array in $_POST.
- This should make your SQL query return multiple results, which means `$questions` would hold all of those results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for attempt but it did not work. The query isn't correct when attempting your code, it doesn't recognise if I select single student or single question, and it is still doing same output when selecting all students and all questions from drop down menu it just didn't work at all, but its a good attempt nonetheless?

Comment: Are you sure multiple student ids are being passed in via $_POST?

Comment: What I know is that with the dynamic where clause, it does not generate a condition in WHERE clause for student ('sa.StudentId = ?`) if student selected is `All` which value is `0`. This  works similar for question as well where if `All` selected for question then no `(q.QuestionId = ?)`

Comment: You see before the dynamic where clause if I just kept the query as it was (just ignore the dynamic WHERE clause in code above and imagine the WHERE clause was simply `q.SessionId = ?`, then it displayed all students and the questions they answered correctly as I wanted. But add a dynamic WHERE clause and something is wrong. I am not sure if multipe student ids are being passed, if there is a way to check then I am happy to know how to check for it

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST['student'])` and you'll be able to see what it contains.

Comment: I have updated my update in the question. Please have a read and I think you will have all the information to understand what is happeing

Comment: Hi, was the information helpful to you? give me a comment on any issues you may have :)

Comment: I really need your help, do you have any other ideas because I need to get this finished by tommorow but I have no clue what to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a closing } after

```
// You only need to call bind_param once
```

Now your

```
if(!empty($where)) {
```

Doesn't end in the place it should end in...

Comment: Hi, trid moving the bracket but did not change the output